# swift 2.1 table view controller segue to view delegate errors with unexpectedly found nil

Tags: ios, swift

Ive research this and i'm pretty sure this is the correct way but I keep getting

```
 fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

on the prepareForSegue line

```
 selectSingleVC!.delegate = self
```

The relevant bits of code are here. I'm not sure why the nil is there and its driving me mad :-)

```
class FriendsChatViewController: UITableViewController, UIActionSheetDelegate, SelectSingleViewControllerDelegate, SelectMultipleViewControllerDelegate {

...

@IBAction func compose(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

weak var wself: FriendsChatViewController? = self

let action = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) { _ in
}

let singleAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Single recipient", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { _ in
    if let _ = wself {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("selectSingleSegue", sender: self)

    }
}

let multipleAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Multiple recipients", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { _ in
    if let _ = wself {
       self.performSegueWithIdentifier("selectMultipleSegue", sender: self)

    }
}


action.addAction(cancelAction)
action.addAction(singleAction)
action.addAction(multipleAction)

self.presentViewController(action, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

...

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "messagesChatSegue" {
        let chatVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ChatViewController
        //chatVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
        let groupId = sender as! String
        chatVC.groupId = groupId
    } else if segue.identifier == "selectSingleSegue" {
        let selectSingleVC = segue.destinationViewController as? SelectSingleViewController
        print(self)
        selectSingleVC!.delegate = self  <-- ERROR is here
    } else if segue.identifier == "selectMultipleSegue" {
        let selectMultipleVC = segue.destinationViewController as? SelectMultipleViewController
        selectMultipleVC!.delegate = self
    }

}
```

This is relevant sections of my SelectSingleViewController

```
protocol SelectSingleViewControllerDelegate {
func didSelectSingleUser(user: PFUser)
}

class SelectSingleViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

var friends = [PFObject]()
var user = PFUser()
var delegate: SelectSingleViewControllerDelegate!

...

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in
        if self.delegate != nil {
            let friendObject = self.friends[indexPath.row]
            let friend = friendObject["user"] as! PFUser
            self.user = friend

            print(self.user)
            self.delegate.didSelectSingleUser(self.user)

        }
    })
}
```

Ive been racking my brain on this for hours and need some assistance in my error. Thanks

Comment: What do you get when you log the value of `segue.destinationViewController`? I'm guessing it isn't actually a `SelectSingleViewController`

Comment: Ahh you are right it isn't..its a UINavigationController

Answer (score 0):

Put a check on `selectSingleVC`. Its crashing because `selectSingleVC` is `nil` and you are being sure it of type `SelectSingleViewController` and trying to use force unwrapping `!` operation.

My guess is the segue with identifier `selectSingleSegue` is not linked to `SelectSingleViewController` in story board. Please double check your connections.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned by @dan my `segue.destinationViewController` was equal to `UINavigationViewController` and because of changes in Swift 2

```
let selectSingleVC = segue.destinationViewController.topViewController as? SelectSingleViewController
```

will no longer work. My revised code is

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "messagesChatSegue" {

        let chatVC  = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! ChatViewController

        //chatVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
        let groupId = sender as! String
        chatVC.groupId = groupId
    } else if segue.identifier == "selectSingleSegue" {
        let selectSingleVC = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! SelectSingleViewController
        print(segue.destinationViewController)
        selectSingleVC.delegate = self
    } else if segue.identifier == "selectMultipleSegue" {
        let selectMultipleVC = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as!SelectMultipleViewController
        selectMultipleVC.delegate = self
    }

}
```